# Treacherous ActiveRecord behavior?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have a **Post** class with a **vote** method which creates a **Vote** instance

This doesn't work

```
def vote(options)
   vote = self.votes.create(options)
   return vote if vote.valid?
   nil
end
```

This does work

```
def vote(options)
   options[:post] = self
   vote = self.votes.create(options)
   return vote if vote.valid?
   nil
end
```

Shouldn't the **.create** call automatically add the :post association?

CLARIFICATION

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :votes
end

class Vote < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, :counter_cache => true
  belongs_to :post
end

Comment: How does it not work? Further explanation is required.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have

```
has_many :votes
```

declared in your Post model?

At what point are you calling the vote method in the object's lifecycle?  It it part of a callback method?

Comment: I call the vote method after the object has been created (and saved).

The vote method call is not part of a callback.

Comment: If it didn't have has_many :votes than self.votes.create would have caused an error in both cases.

Comment: @Alexandre If you're calling vote after the object has been created, why does it create a new one?

Comment: @EmFi Sorry, I didn't understand your question. Which object has been created when a new one is created?

Comment: It may also be easier if you provided more model code and the commands that you're using to test in the console.

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to debug if you wrote it as `self.votes.create!(options)` because then it will throw an exception with an error message. You can take this out once you fix the problem, but you should think about what your method should return if it doesn't work.

Does it make sense for `Post#vote` to return `nil`? Why should casting a vote fail? How does your code handle the nil value returned by `Post#vote`?

Maybe you should just re-write it as:

```
def vote(options)
  self.votes.create!(options)
end
```

Comment: It would return nil if a user had already voted, in which case the vote would be invalid.

Comment: OK. Did you try switching to create! to see what the error from ActiveRecord is?